# Making a program/application using xml

Tags: xml

I am a noob in xml. I have read w3school tutorial on XML. Now I want to do some practice. Can anyody suggest a simple program, application which I can make which use xml in some way. Any ideas :) ?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: a simple winForm, console app.. etc ?? any suggestion

Comment: if you think this answer has helped you, please check it as the correct answer .. that's the protocol of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check those links, they might be of help to you

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387089.aspx
- http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter
- [How to create XML document using XmlDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492705/how-to-create-xml-document-using-xmldocument)