# Create file and write xml there (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, win-universal-app

I writing UWP app for windows 10 mobile.

I created xml like this:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement el = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Order"));
        el.SetAttribute("CallConfirm", "1");
        el.SetAttribute("PayMethod", "");
        el.SetAttribute("QtyPerson", "");
        el.SetAttribute("Type", "1");
        el.SetAttribute("PayStateID", "0");
        el.SetAttribute("Remark", "{StreetName} , ..");
        el.SetAttribute("RemarkMoney", "0");
        el.SetAttribute("TimePlan", "");
        el.SetAttribute("Brand", "1");
        el.SetAttribute("DiscountPercent", "0");
        el.SetAttribute("BonusAmount", "0");
        el.SetAttribute("Department", "");

        XmlElement el2 = (XmlElement)el.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Customer"));

        el2.SetAttribute("Login", "");
        el2.SetAttribute("FIO", "{FIO}");

        XmlElement el3 = (XmlElement)el.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Address"));

        el3.SetAttribute("CityName", "");
        el3.SetAttribute("StationName", "");
        el3.SetAttribute("StreetName", "{StreetName}");
        el3.SetAttribute("House", "{HouseName}");
        el3.SetAttribute("Corpus", "");
        el3.SetAttribute("Building", "");
        el3.SetAttribute("Flat", "{FlatName}");
        el3.SetAttribute("Porch", "");
        el3.SetAttribute("Floor", "");
        el3.SetAttribute("DoorCode", "");

        XmlElement el4 = (XmlElement)el.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Phone"));

        el4.SetAttribute("Code", "{Code}");
        el4.SetAttribute("Number", "{Phone}");

        XmlElement el5 = (XmlElement)el.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Products"));
```

I want to create .xml file and write this xml to it.

I try save it like this  `doc.Save("data.xml");` but have this error

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'  Murakami
```

How I can make this?

Thank's very much for help!

Comment: Did you try searching how to save an `XmlDocument`? You'd get a lot of results!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create XML document using XmlDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492705/how-to-create-xml-document-using-xmldocument)

Comment: @CharlesMager it's an Universal App

Comment: @ЕвгенийСухомлин there are some posts here on SO about this, I didn't find an exact dupe then I just point you to an example: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XmlDocument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're writing Windows 10 universal app, `XmlDocument.Save(string)` is unavailable. Instead, use

```
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Create))
    {
        doc.Save(fs);
    }
```

Comment: Is this solution working? For me it is giving unauthorized access error

Comment: hi   i  just wanted to mention that I was working with core net 1.0 in ubuntu 16.04 and I came out the same error.but when i do it this way keeps me xml thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working on windows universal app.

you need to use the code below to save file in storage:

```
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await doc.SaveToFileAsync(file);
```

Comment: Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream' Has this error. –

Comment: Please, see this solution. In UWP, this way help you to save xml file.