# xml creation in C#

Tags: c#, json, xml

I want final xml as follows...

```
<Programs>
  <Program><id>4</id><isRead>true</isRead><isWrite>false</isWrite></Program>
  <Program><id>8</id><isRead>true</isRead><isWrite>true</isWrite></Program>
</programs>
```

now following is the code written

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"programs",null);
xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);


foreach (dynamic item in access)
{
  XmlNode myXmlNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(item.ToString(), "program");
  rootNode.AppendChild(myXmlNode); //error
}
```

where in myXmlNode.InnerXml, I am already getting following

```
<Program><id>4</id><isRead>true</isRead><isWrite>false</isWrite></Program>
```

And so, running the loop for all  children to add in  which is parent. But I am getting error for line //error as marked above. Error is:

> The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node,
>   because the specified node is the wrong type.

Comment: for the pretty printing part (multi-line and indentation) see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1123731/1132334

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode` is interesting choice. Have you been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11492705/1997232)?

Comment: want to pass this xml as parameter to sql SP

Comment: @ghetal if you're looking to deserialize you can do this using the inverse of what I suggested in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert different type of xml node. You could use `ImportNode` to apply it.

```
foreach (dynamic item in access)
{
    XmlNode myXmlNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(item.ToString(), "program");
    rootNode.AppendChild(rootNode.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(myXmlNode.FirstChild,true));
}
```

Comment: still gives error: Cannot import nodes of type 'Document'.

Comment: You can't import a document type as node. I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks.. with minimal changes I could achieve what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you create a model for what you are looking to create in XML,  then serialize a list of the model to XML.

The reason being that you will end up with something far more maintainable.

Your model would be something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public bool IsWrite { get; set; }
}
```

And you can serialize it by following this article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/815813/how-to-serialize-an-object-to-xml-by-using-visual-c

Answer (score 0):

I've used the XmlSerializer library myself a few times.

```
public class Program
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public bool IsWrite { get; set; }
}

public class XmlTemplate
{
    public List<Program> Programs { get; set; }
}

class MainProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xmlTemplate = new XmlTemplate();
        xmlTemplate.Programs = new List<Program>();
        xmlTemplate.Programs.Add(new Program() { Id = 123, IsRead = true, IsWrite = false });
        xmlTemplate.Programs.Add(new Program() { Id = 456, IsRead = false, IsWrite = true });

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlTemplate));
        var stream = new StringWriter();

        serializer.Serialize(stream, xmlTemplate);

        Console.WriteLine(stream.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

This outputs the XML in the following format:

```
<XmlTemplate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Programs>
    <Program>
      <Id>123</Id>
      <IsRead>true</IsRead>
      <IsWrite>false</IsWrite>
    </Program>
    <Program>
      <Id>456</Id>
      <IsRead>false</IsRead>
      <IsWrite>true</IsWrite>
    </Program>
  </Programs>
</XmlTemplate>
```

Comment: have reached nearer to solution, so want to see if this way can it be achieved or not

Comment: It can. By using XmlSerializer and a template class, you can both serialize from object to XML and deserialize from XML to object.